# puppeteer fileChooser: how to use URL instead of local file path?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, glitch-framework

I have the http link of a video file (cloud storage) and I want to select that file in filechooser.

I am using cloud hosting (glitch), so I don't want to store that file to local storage.

```
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
page.waitForFileChooser(),
page.click('#select-files-button')
]);
await fileChooser.accept(["https://examle.mp4"]);
```

It only seems to accept a local file path, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

As you could have guessed, it obviously accepts only local files, you can download your desired file first (with `request` module or even `http(s?)` module), then pass it to puppeteer.

Comment: but i am using glitch cloud hosting , btw thanks i will try.